# Driven oscillator with constant velocity

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, spring

I am trying to simulate a driven oscillator of sorts on the computer. I have a 1D spring-mass system, attached to a point in space. To make the math easier, I'm assuming the attachment point is right at the spring's equilibrium position. The total force of the system is:

$F = k(P_a-P_m)$

where $P_m$ is the mass's position and $P_a$ is the attachment point. Later, I'd like to add dampening, but for now I'm keeping it simple.

So, I want to move $P_a$ around with constant velocity. How do I calculate where $P_m$ will be in $t$ seconds, given an initial $P_a$, $P_m$ and velocity for $P_a$?

**My attempts:**

It seems like I'd need to solve it as a differential equation. I haven't learned how to do differential equations though, so I'm not sure how to proceed. I plugged a few numbers in, and it looks like the motion of $P_a$ only affects the amplitude and phase of a normal spring's motion. Though, it seems like it might even shift the sin wave vertically, in some cases. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newton's second law says $F=ma=m\frac{dP_m^2}{dt^2}$. Substituting yields

$$m\frac{dP_m^2}{dt^2} = k(P_a-P_m)$$

Since $P_a$ is moving at constant velocity, we can substite $vt$ for $P_a$. Doing this and rearranging, we find

$$m\frac{dP_m^2}{dt^2} + kP_m = kvt$$

This is indeed a differential equation, a second order inhomogeneous linear ordinary differential equation in fact. I recommend [khan academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/differential-equations/second-order-differential-equations) to help you there.

Comment: When you substitute $vt$ for $P_a$, you are assuming $P_a$ starts at zero, right? So, I'd just need to shift $P_m$ over by $-P_a$ accordingly, correct?

Comment: @Azmisov not sure exactly what you're asking. Yes I'm assuming $P_a(t=0)=0$